# How to get all the posts that a page is tagged in using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Since FQL is deprecated from 2.1 onwards.Is there any way to get all the posts that a page is tagged in using Graph API.

tried {page_id}/tagged but it shows only the page's posts not the posts that a page was tagged.

I want to query the posts using graph API by a user on their own wall that tags the page.is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

isn't this a functionality of the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed) which Accessing it is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. Applications to the API are not open at this time.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I an look for the information regarding facebook approval of public feed api....

Comment: as stated in the page of the Public Feed API you cannot apply to use the API at this time.

Comment: Using fql I am able to get these post but this is working only for one fb user ,still not able to figure out what is different with this account.in order to get tagged posts I queried "stream" ..